# Why use $rootScope to share data across controllers when factories can do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory, angularjs-rootscope

My understanding is that $rootScope is some kind of global variable which allows it to be shared across controllers. Factories can also do the same thing. So, why not use a factory instead? When should one use $rootScope and when should one use factory given that they serve almost the same purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AngularJS FAQ already answers this pretty well [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil):

> **$rootScope exists, but it can be used for evil**
>
> Scopes in Angular form
>   a hierarchy, prototypally inheriting from a root scope at the top of
>   the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a
>   controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to
>   the whole app. For these, you can inject $rootScope and set values on
>   it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope,
>   these values will be available to the expressions attached to
>   directives like ng-show just like values on your local $scope.
>
> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly,
>   like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language.
>   In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to
>   put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a
>   service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily
>   tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to
>   store and return bits of data.

Answer (score 1):

The $rootScope is provided to see the hierarchy of scopes in the application. If you have a task to modify the hierarchy directly (which is very rare: for example manually fix a memory leak caused by a 3rd party library or some global events emitter), then use $rootScope.
In all other 99% cases services should be used.
Another opinions can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/EUbsKCpAASo).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store some data and keep it after route change - service (factory) is the best solution. `$rootScope` can do the same thing, but it's global, as you mentioned, so there's a chance to break you data. `$rootScope` is useful when you need some global events (`$rootScope.$broadcast`), for example user login/logout, but not for data storage.